# Selected option doesnt work in form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using Contao as CMS and for a filter, I need to build my own select.
This is my Code, what is working so fare:

```
<form action="media-center" id="cc_filter_339" name="cc_filter_339" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onchange="this.submit();">
  <div class="formbody">
    <select class="" name="language">
      <option value="language_reset">Sprache</option>
      <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
      <option value="en">English</option>
      <option value="fr">Français</option>
      <option value="nl">Nederlands</option>
    </select>         
    <div class="widget submit_container clearall clear_all_filters">
      <input type="submit" id="ctrl_cc_filter_339_clearall" class="submit clearall clear_all_filters" value="Filter zurücksetzten" name="cc_filter_339_clearall">     
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The only problem is, the option "Sprache" is always selcted, it dosnt mater which option I click.

I hope you guys can help my with that.

Comment: It is working as usual, i tested it!

Comment: Yes but when I choose e.g. "Deutsch", the pages refreshes with the right parameter but option "Deutsch" is not selected.

Comment: You need to check what value was selected after form submit and then set it with `selected` there's plenty of guides on how to do this out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `$_GET` value and then add `selected` attribute to your options. Do like below:-

```
<form action="media-center" id="cc_filter_339" name="cc_filter_339" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onchange="this.submit();">
  <div class="formbody">
    <select class="" name="language">
      <option value="language_reset" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='anguage_reset'){echo "selected";}?>>Sprache</option>
      <option value="de" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option>
      <option value="en" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='en'){echo "selected";}?>>English</option>
      <option value="fr" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='fr'){echo "selected";}?>>Français</option>
      <option value="nl" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='nl'){echo "selected";}?>>Nederlands</option>
    </select>         
    <div class="widget submit_container clearall clear_all_filters">
      <input type="submit" id="ctrl_cc_filter_339_clearall" class="submit clearall clear_all_filters" value="Filter zurücksetzten" name="cc_filter_339_clearall">     
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I've got one last question, why isnt the option displayed? <?php if (!$filterUrl == "www.domain.de"){?><option value="de" <?php if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='de'){echo "selected";}?>>Deutsch</option><?php } ?>

Comment: @fr3d  please ask new question regarding this. thanks